# Displaying data from API (Store) in template - can't render retrieved record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I use a service to request data, then the service is injected into a component. Data is retrieved from Ember Mirage.

My problem is that I can't display the data as a property, even though when this property is used in computedProperty, the computedProperty correctly computes and displays.

Component template in Emblem:

```
.notifications-number {{notificationService.countUnread.content}}
each notificationService.notifications.content as |notification|
  span {{notification.text}}
```

Notification service:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service('store'),

  // render bugs out
  notifications: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('notification')
  }.property(),

  // renders correctly
  countUnread: function() {
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({
      promise: this.get('notifications').then((notifications) => {
        return notifications.get('length')
      })
    });
  }.property(),
});
```

Mirage config:

```
this.get('/notifications', () => {
    return {
      data: [
        {id: 1, type: 'notification', text: 'hi im notification', link: ''},
        {id: 2, type: 'notification', text: 'hi im notification 2', link: 'google.com'}            
      ]
    };
  });
```

I have similar problem with another service and component where retrieved data is not an array but an object.

- `{{myService.myProperty}}` renders `<(subclass of Ember.ObjectProxy):ember404>`
- `{{myService.myProperty.content}}` renders `<my-app@model:myModel::ember580:1>`
- `{{myService.myProperty.content.myModelField}}` renders nothing.

Everything worked fine when I manually set values in store on app init, but doesn't work when actual asynchronous requests are sent to API mock.

Comment: Are you sure `countUnread` works properly? You're using a `PromiseObject`, but you're actually returning a value (`length` which is a number). Values can't be proxied to, you'd have to return something like `{ value: notifications.get('length') }`. And do `{{countUnread.value}}` in the template.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct format for the Mirage payload?

Comment: It seems it really worked properly although I don't know why. Maybe it coincidentally computed a right number? Anyway, you are right, main issue was incorrect JSON format. I'll add my answer later today.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was incorrect JSON format for my adapter (I think some variables were hyphenated instead of underscored).

This is not correct way to load data from API to a service though. Now I think the best is to load data in routes/application.js model() hook and push it to the service in setupController(). This is how it looks right now:

```
  // routes/application.js

  model() {
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        user: this.get('store').queryRecord('user', {}),
        notifications: this.get('store').findAll('notification', { reload: true })
      })
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(...arguments)

    if (model)
      this.set('notificationService.notifications', model.notifications.sortBy('createdAt').reverse())
  },
```

And in service it can be then used without any promises, relying on computed property:

```
  // services/notificationService.js

  countUnread: function() {
    let notifications = this.get('notifications')
    if (notifications)
      return notifications.filterBy('read', false).get('length')
  }.property('notifications')
```

And of course no `.content` needs to be used in any controller or template.